# How to ignore pd.NaT in max?

Tags: python-3.x, max, missing-data, python-datetime

Short: how to ignore `pd.NaT` in a list put into `max`?

```
import datetime
max([pd.NaT, datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1), datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1)])
```

The expected output is `Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00')`. Even if this question seems to be a standard problem, I couldn't find a solution beside this unpythonic one:

```
max(pd.DataFrame([pd.NaT, datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1), datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1)]).dropna()[0])
```

Comment: as an aside, for float NaN's you can use `np.nanmax`, but that unfortunately throws AttributeError when NaT is introduced

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now you are using pyhton's max function. Instead you can use pandas series max which automatically handles NaT:

```
pd.Series([pd.NaT, datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1), datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1)]).max()
```